# CloudStickyNotes.jar not working in gnome

Tags: gnome, java, stickynotes

I am trying to use this Java application called Cloud Sticky notes within Gnome, I've used it on Windows and within Elementary os without issue and I've tried to use it in 3 different versions of Gnome.

What's suppose to happen when using the .jar file or at least what happened in elementary os is in place of a system tray icon (which it uses to launch new sticky notes in Windows) a window appears that displays all the settings and a list of collapsed and opened notes, as seen here:

[image]

What happens for me in Gnome is the window doesn't appear, I get a java icon in my Dash/Dock(Gnome Sidebar) that I can't close and it doesn't display anything and each note if they're open from another computer will launch in the Dash with the cloud sticky icon, as seen here:

[image]

I really love this program and Gnome 3 is my favourite DE, but if they can't mesh I don't think I could go on.

Answer (score 0):

For other users that run into this problem.  The root of it is a compatibility issue between Java and the system tray in Gnome 3.  Go to [CloudStickyNotes.com](http://www.CloudStickyNotes.com) and contact support (scroll to the bottom to see the email address).  The owner (me) will send you a build that defaults to the window instead of the system tray.